# AmpScript and JavaScript w/Cloud Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, ssjs

My objective is to insert the subscriberkey into a data extension on JavaScript onclick event. I do not see any viable documentation that works. I've tried passing AmpScript variables to Javascript and I get a 500 error.

I've tried some basic JavaScript insert below from the documentation and get a 500 error.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsAdd.htm

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core","1");

  var arrContacts =  [
      {Email:"jdoe@example.com",FirstName:"John",LastName:"Doe"},
      {Email:"aruiz@example.com",FirstName:"Angel",LastName:"Ruiz"}
     ];

var birthdayDE = DataExtension.Init("birthdayDE");
birthdayDE.Rows.Add(arrContacts);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

SSJS is executed in the backend. Hence once the page is loaded, it will not execute before the page is refreshed. You should create a JSON [Code Resource](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_code_resource.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null), where you put your AmpScript.

You can then call that Code Resource URL in JS on your Cloud Page, passing values as e.g. [Request Parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm). It should read your GET variables, and use [appropriate code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertde.htm) to upsert this data to a data extension.

You can then return the status code of this request in JSON, for your JS to parse and present on the page making the request.